# Equivalence between sequent calculi with different cut rules

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Let G4' be a sequent calculus G4 for classical logic with the addition of the following pair of "left" and "right" cut rules:

[image]

Let now be G4'' a second calculus G4 for classical logic with the addition of the following "general" cut rule:

[image]

I am trying to prove the equivalence between the two calculi G4' and G4''. It is immediate to prove that a sequent derived in G4' can be derived in G4''. About the converse implication, I think it should be possible to prove it by induction on the level of the cut rule (much like a cut elimination proof), but I was wondering if there is a more immediate way to show that any derivation with the "general" cut rule can be rewritten in a derivation that uses the "left" and "right" versions. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: can you use the left and right cut rules to give rules  that derive $\Gamma, A \vdash \Delta$  from  $A \vdash \lnot \Gamma, \Delta$ and vice versa (where $\lnot \Gamma$is means the list of negations of formulas in $\Gamma$)?

Comment: @RobArthan not really. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I should have said the other rules in your calculus, I didn't mean just the cut rules. In the usual Gentzen calculus the $\lnot$-L or  $\lnot$-R rules should help you do what you want..

Comment: @RobArthan I'm having a hard time trying to derive Γ,A⊢Δ from A⊢¬Γ,Δ. I always end up using the general cut rule instead of the left and right ones. Could you give me some help?

Comment: Phil, can you give a reference or a link to the system of rules you are using.